# Target API - Will old devices still support deprecated features?

Tags: java, android, api, deprecated

sorry if this question was already asked but I couldnt find anything.

Starting November 2018 all Android Apps need to target API lvl 26 or else you cant release any new updates. So I understand that when I target my App to API lvl 26 there will be features that wont work anymore. Like for example implicit broadcast receivers. Now my question. Will those old features that are deprecated in API lvl 26 stil work for devices that use older APIs? For example when someone uses a device that runs on API lvl 21. Will those devices still support those features even if my app targets API lvl 26?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is yes . The restriction will be applied as per OS versions . So you should do code by keeping that in mind .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though deprecated methods and functionalities should be avoided, devices that are running API level 21 will still support those features while your app is targeting any API > 21. This is true for any future requirement like this as well, until it is explicitly stated that the features will be removed.

Make sure that your app's min SDK is still at 21 or lower.